# CSS background-image / cover issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me with an issue that is beginning to drive me a little bit insane ...

I am working on a new webpage - [www.romaheritage.co.uk/beta](https://www.romaheritage.co.uk/beta) - and I'm having an issue with a background image near the bottom of the page in the "contact" section. Testing the page with two different browsers, the road image appears in Firefox, but does not appear in Google Chrome and I have no idea why!

What's more frustrating is I have a background image set at the top of the page and this works in both browsers without an issue!

the CSS I'm using is this (although feel free to inspect the website itself);

```
background-image: url(../img/contact.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Any help anyone can give me would be gratefully received, because a bit like Neo in the Matrix, I'm now just seeing lines of code but getting lost in it ...

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has. You also shouldn't be using vendor prefixes.

Comment: Well spotted with the <meta> tags ... I'll remove them!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with `background-attachment: fixed;` remove that to make just make the image appear. Or add `backface-visibility: hidden;`, to `.contact-parallax-bg` restore the fixed effect.

Comment: Then try adding backface-visibility: hidden; to .contact-parallax-bg

Comment: ahhhh, now this works ... and if I add back in the background-attachment: fixed, that you first told me to remove, I get the parrallax back, excellent, thank you!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
.contact-us-section{
     position: relative;
}
```

remove position relative and you will have "parallax" effect and image will be there

Comment: if I remove the position relative, it still doesn't work (show the image) in Google Chrome, and messes up the top image in Firefox ...